# DataTables fails to display Ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to display data from Ajax source, using this HTML:

```
<table class="table-striped data-table" data-src="https://my.site/json-url" data-columns='["id","sku","name","base_stock","stock","sales"]'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>SKU</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Initial Stock</th>
            <th>Current Stock</th>
            <th>Sales</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And this JS:

```
$('.data-table').each(function(){
    var src = $(this).data('src');
    var cols = $(this).data('columns').map(x => {return {data: x};});
    $(this).DataTable({
        "responsive": true,
        "ajax": src,
        "columns": cols
    });
});
```

Where, `https://my.site/json-url` normally responds with:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1515,
      "sku": "",
      "name": "Test Simple",
      "base_stock": 10,
      "stock": 10,
      "sales": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 1512,
      "sku": "BWTEST",
      "name": "Test Variable - Black / White",
      "base_stock": 9,
      "stock": 9,
      "sales": 0
    },
    {
      "id": 1513,
      "sku": "CLRTEST",
      "name": "Test Variable - Multi-Color",
      "base_stock": 4,
      "stock": 4,
      "sales": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I'm getting the error: `Uncaught TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for "length" in "id"` at `jquery.min.js:2:1065`. Could someone help with this?

NOTE: I can see that no ajax request is actually made to `https://my.site/json-url` so the error appears to be happening even prior to ajax call.

Comment: In case you are curious about the resultant structure, this is what the options array looks like in console: `{
    "responsive": true,
    "ajax": "https://my.site/json-url",
    "columns": [
      "id",
      "sku",
      "name",
      "base_stock",
      "stock",
      "sales"
    ],
    "src": "https://my.site/json-url",
    "aoColumns": [
      "id",
      "sku",
      "name",
      "base_stock",
      "stock",
      "sales"
    ]
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your custom `data-` tags are conflicting with the datatables `data-` tags.

> https://www.datatables.net/manual/options#HTML-5-data-attributes
>
> DataTables can also use initialisation options read from HTML5 data-* attributes. This provides a mechanism for setting options directly in your HTML, rather than using Javascript

Rename your `data-` attributes and you'll be fine (as long as you don't pick another conflicting name...)

For confirmation, removing everything to the bare minimum, to rule out the ajax and datatables options also gives the error:

```js
$('.data-table').each(function() {
  $(this).DataTable({
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table-striped data-table" data-src="https://my.site/json-url" data-columns='["id","sku","name","base_stock","stock","sales"]'>
</table>
```

while changing your `data-` attribute names removes the error

```js
$('.data-table').each(function() {
  $(this).DataTable({
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="table-striped data-table" data-my-src="https://my.site/json-url" data-my-columns='["id","sku","name","base_stock","stock","sales"]'>
</table>
```

(don't use `-my-` it's just for demonstration)

Comment: You are a saviour! I had gone through all the commonly suggested solutions, including columns structure, manual data, even separate ajax calls. It never clicked that problem could be with data-* attributes.